# Is there a handy mnemonic or visual aid for all the basic set theory function relations, such as $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, visualization, mnemonic

Glancing at Appendix A of John Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, I noticed the following list of rules:

[image]

I'm familiar with rules like these and have no trouble proving them—that's not my question. Rather, I wonder if there are convenient visuals or general principles that make rules like these easier to remember and even understand. Why do pre-images preserve set-theoretic structure better than images? Why is the structure of unions preserved under images, but not intersections? Again, I'm not looking for a proof of such things because I already know how to prove them. But the proofs are mechanical and don't seem to offer any deep or general insights. Is there a visualization or way of thinking about these rules that makes even the obscure ones, such as (k), quickly comprehensible without the full "mechanical" proof?

Comment: Draw Venn Diagrams.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Do those help one understand how the asymmetries between images and pre-images manifest?

Comment: If you know category theory, direct image is left adjoint to the inverse image, so (a) and (f) are the counit and the unit, (b) and (g) say that $f^{-1}$, and $f$ are functors, (d) and (h) are true because adjoints commute with (co)limits and so on.

Comment: I can reconstruct a function if I know all of the preimages but I can't reconstruct it if all I know is the image. I believe this is the underlying reason that they are comparatively well-behaved.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But if you know all the images, then you know all the images of singleton sets, and hence you know the function.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев I don't know enough category theory to make sense of that, but I'm trying to learn it.

Comment: @WillG if you restrict the domain to singletons it's not the same function. Almost no interesting functions have domains that are singletons.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Let $f:A\to B$, and suppose you are given all the images $f(U)$ for all $U\subseteq A$. Then in particular you are given $f(\{x\})$ for all $x\in A$, so you can trivially reconstruct $f$. This is why I'm not sure what you meant in your first comment.

Comment: I think you were pointing out that if you know all the pre-images $f(V)$ for all $V\subseteq B$, then you can reconstruct $f$. But I'm saying this is not particular to pre-images.

Comment: There are a lot of properties here, and each one has its own reasoning.  Sometimes it helps to write a one-sentence summary of the proof - or a description of why a subset might not be an equality.